# Pointer to a struct included into struct

Tags: linux, pointers, struct, typedef, declaration

I am working with serial port under Linux. Because I have few interfaces I've defined two structure as :

```
typedef struct
{
   int  handle;
   unsigned int port;
   unsigned short baudRate;
   unsigned char parity;
   char  device[128];
} tS_PORT;

typedef struct
{
   unsigned char testSts;
   unsigned char testRet;
   tS_PORT sPort; 
} tR_PORT;
```

A variable R01 has been declared `tR_PORT R01 = { 5,0 };`

How to work with a pointer on tS_PORT ?

I tried the following code without expected result.

```
int test(void)
{
   int ret;
   ret = sOpen(&R01->sPort); // or ? ret = sOpen(R01->&sPort);   
   return 0;
}

static int sOpen(tS_PORT *pPort)
{
   pPort->handle = open(pPort->device, O_RDWR | O_NOCTTY);
   if(pPort->handle < 0)
   {
      perror("open:");
      return (-1);
   }
   return (pPort->handle);
}

... few functions

static int sClose(tS_PORT *pPort)
{
   return (close(pPort->handle));
}
```

EDIT 1 :

After taking in account Kerrek SB's response. It works but a last function doesn't return the expected value.

```
int test(void)
{
   int ret;
   int closeRet;
   ret = sOpen(&R01.sPort);
   printf("ret = %d\n", ret);  
   closeRet = sClose(&R01.sPort);
   printf("closeRet = %d\n", closeRet);
   printf("handle = %d\n", R01.sPort.handle);
   return 0;
}

static int sOpen(tS_PORT *pPort)
{
   pPort->handle = open(pPort->device, O_RDWR | O_NOCTTY);
   if(pPort->handle < 0)
   {
      perror("open:");
      return (-1);
   }
   return (pPort->handle);
}

... few functions

static int sClose(tS_PORT *pPort)
{
   return (close(pPort->handle));
}
```

Which returns :

```
   ret = 4;  
   closeRet = 0
   handle = 4
```

Why handle is not equal to 0 the port is always opened, isn't ?

Comment: The return values look fine. In `printf("handle = %d\n", R01.sPort.handle);` unless you set `R01.sPort.handle` to the return of `close`, you would expect it to still contain the file descriptor number.

Comment: Thank ! `unless you set R01.sPort.handle to the return of close` you are right ! It is like is currently done into the sOpen function by using `pPort->handle = open()`. I suppose it's not but is it possible to write `pPort->handle = close(pPort->handle)` before returning 0 into the sClose function ?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with `pPort->handle = close(pPort->handle)`. But, if you are using `handle` later in comparisons where you expect it to be `0` from the return, then just be aware it may not be `0` if there is an error on `close`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want `&R01.sPort`. Note that `R01` is not a pointer.